# How to labeled multiple vertex with same label?

Tags: tikz-graphs

In the following graph I had labeled two vertices as "3". Now whenever I tried to draw an edge between vertex "1" to vertex "3"(Right). The edge always drawn on left vertex "3".

I want to draw an edge between vertex "1" and right vertex "3". How I can draw?And also I want to increase label size of vertex.How to do this?

```
\documentclass[legalpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=22cm,paperwidth=22cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\SetVertexNormal[Shape      = circle,
                 FillColor  = Black,
                 LineWidth  = 2pt,
                 InnerSep =  0pt,
                                   ]
\SetUpEdge[lw         = 3pt,
           color      = black,
           labelcolor = white,
           labelcolor = white,
           labeltext  = black,
           labelstyle = {sloped above,draw,text=black}
           ]


\begin{center}



\begin{tikzpicture}

    \Vertex[x=0,y=0,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{3}
     \Vertex[x=10,y=0,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{4}
      \Vertex[x=5,y=5,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{1}
      \Vertex[x=5,y=-5,LabelOut=true,Lpos=180,LableStyle{lw=8pt}]{2}
       \Vertex[x=0,y=-10,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{4}
        \Vertex[x=10,y=-10,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{3}
         \Edge(1)(3)
         \Edge(3)(4)
         \Edge(4)(2)
         \Edge(2)(3)
         \Edges(1,2,3)





\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

enter image description here

Comment: ,@kalpeshmpopat `I want to draw an edge between vertex "1" and right vertex "3".` It is already drawn, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have several vertices with the same label but different inner name, use the `L=<text>` option to assign the label and use a different internal name (`3a` in my example); in this way, you will have two vertices with the same label `3` but with different internal names `3` and `3a` allowing you to use those different names for the edges or any other possibility. I did the same for the two vertices labelled `4`.

To change the label size, I had to patch the internal `\@@vertex` and define a command `\LabelSize` which defaults to `\normalsize\rmfamily`. Redefine this to suit your needs (see the line marked `%Here` in wxhich I changed it to `\LARGE\rmfamily`).

```
\documentclass[legalpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=22cm,paperwidth=22cm,bottom=0.5cm,top=0.5cm,left=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\LabelFont{\normalsize\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@@vertex}
  {\cmdGR@vertex@style}
  {font=\LabelFont,\cmdGR@vertex@style}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\SetVertexNormal[
  Shape = circle,
  FillColor  = Black,
  LineWidth  = 2pt,
  InnerSep =  0pt,
  MinSize=1cm,
]

\SetUpEdge[
  lw = 3pt,
  color = black,
  labelcolor = white,
  labelcolor = white,
  labeltext  = black\fontsize{30}{36}\selectfont,
  labelstyle = {sloped above,draw}
]

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\LabelFont{\LARGE\rmfamily}% Here
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \Vertex[x=0,y=0,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90,L=3]{3a}
  \Vertex[x=10,y=0,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90,L=4]{4a}
  \Vertex[x=5,y=5,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{1}
  \Vertex[x=5,y=-5,LabelOut=true,Lpos=180,LableStyle{lw=8pt}]{2}
  \Vertex[x=0,y=-10,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{4}
  \Vertex[x=10,y=-10,LabelOut=true,Lpos=90]{3}
  \Edge(1)(3a)
  \Edge(3)(4)
  \Edge(4)(2)
  \Edge(2)(3)
  \Edges(1,2,3)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina.How i can increase label size?

Comment: @kalpeshmpotat You're welcome. I had to leave in a hurry. In some time, when I return home, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok Gonzalo Medina

Comment: @kalpeshmpopat Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh My God!!! Sir You Are Genius.Thank You So So Much Sir